# What does the notation "population proportion p = n:m" mean in statistics?

Tags: statistics

What does the notation "population proportion p = n:m" mean in statistics? I looked everywhere (Google, this forum, KhanAcademy, etc.) and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: can you give us some context?

Comment: It perhaps refers to a ratio: writing $n:m$ is the same as $\frac{n}{m}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real life example of using ratios is in aspect ratios for monitors and televisions. One of the most common aspect ratios is $16:9$. This means that the horizontal length of the monitor is $\frac{16}{9}$ times bigger than the vertical length. Such resolutions include $1920 \times 1080$, $1280 \times 720$. If you simplify $\frac{1920}{1080}$ and $\frac{1280}{720}$, they both simplify to $\frac{16}{9}$.

Let's say you were given a ratio of $\text{girls}:\text{boys}$ as $3:2$. This means that in this group, there are $\frac{3}{2}=1.5$ times as many girls in that group than boys. If you were given the amount of boys as $50$, you can calculate the number of girls to be $50\times \frac{3}{2}=75 \text{ girls}$.

Similarly, if you were given the number of girls to be $90$, you can divide the ratio to get the number of boys: $90/\frac{3}{2}=90\times \frac{2}{3}=60 \text{ boys}$

Hope this helps.